# function to add item to beginning of an array without unshift method

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am trying to implement a function to add an item to the beginning of an array without using the unshift or splice methods, just array.length. Everything I do so far just overwrites what is already existing at index 0. Any help would be appreciated!

```
LetsUnshift = function(array) { 
 for (var i = array.length - 1; i >0; i--) {
    array[i +1] = array[i];
 }
 array[0] = item;
};
```

Comment: this question is unclear.. what do you want to do? are you performing a book exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
 var LetsUnshift = function(array, item) { 
      for (var i = array.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
         array[i +1] = array[i];
      }
      array[0] = item;
 };
```

The issue with your code is the condition `i>0`, which prevents the first element from being shifted to the right.

Comment: Ah yes, I knew it would be some missing operator I couldn't identify! Thank you for your explanation too, that clarifies it for me.

Comment: this is the right answer

Answer (score 2):

Keeping the same reference, you could use *ES 6's* [`Array.prototype.copyWithin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/copyWithin)

```
var arr = ['b', 'c', 'd'],
    x = 'a';
++arr.length;
arr.copyWithin(1, 0);
arr[0] = x;

arr; // ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

---

You could reverse twice,

```
var arr = ['b', 'c', 'd'];
arr.reverse().push('a');
arr.reverse();

arr; // ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

---

You could re-push the whole thing,

```
var arr = ['b', 'c', 'd'],
    a2 = arr.slice();
arr.length = 0;
arr.push('a');
Array.prototype.push.apply(arr, a2);

arr; // ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

---

You could iterate with `while`, similar to your `for`

```
var arr = ['b', 'c', 'd'],
    i = arr.length;
while (i-- > 0)
    arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
arr[0] = 'a';

arr; // ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

---

If your goal is to create a **new reference** you could re-write either of those last two, e.g.

```
var arr = ['b', 'c', 'd'],
    a2 = ['a'];
Array.prototype.push.apply(a2, arr);

a2; // ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

---

If we're just code-golfing,

```
var arr = ['b', 'c', 'd'],
    a2 = Array.bind(null, 'a').apply(null, arr);

a2; // ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
letsUnshift = function(array, itemToAdd) { 
  return array.reduce(function(newArray, value){
    newArray.push(value);
    return newArray;
  }, [itemToAdd]);
};
letsUnshift([2,3,4], 1); //returns [1,2,3,4] and doesn't modify original array
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just called the function instead and start it from `arr.length-1` down to `>= 0` as suggested in another answer

```js
var item = 15, i, arr = [11, 23, 33, 54, 17, 89];
LetsUnshift(arr);
function LetsUnshift(arr) {
    for (i = arr.length-1; i >= 0; --i) {
        arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
    }
    arr[0] = item;
};
console.log(arr);

//OUTPUT: [15, 11, 23, 33, 54, 17, 89]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const array=[1,2,3]
const target=3

function addElementAtStarting(array, target){
    return [target, ...array]
}
```